# Function select same and similar, count them, return friendly name and count

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, similarity

Hey guys this question is kind of a followup with my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470553/counting-database-entries-that-are-the-same-mysqli-num-rows). I created a function to count votes per column for a contest that we hold annually. The problem is that, with text fields people don't always spell things correctly, or use punctuation the same, also the backslashes end up getting included into the database more often than they should (which makes me wonder if sometimes they're getting double escaped or something but, there are already too many entries)

Anyway, my function looks like this. I am wondering if there's a way to clean it up. For instance if one character is off then it's pretty safe to assume that they're the same place or something.

```
function get_results_for($column) {
    global $dbc;
    $rowcount = "";
    //This portion fetches unique entries that aren't empty
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT $column ";
                $query .= "FROM newbob ";
                $query .= "WHERE $column != '' ";
                $query .= "ORDER BY $column ASC";


                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                if (!$result){
    die ("Database query failed.");
}

//and I want this portion to count how many there are that are the same, and
//just add it next to it.
while($entries = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 foreach ($entries as $entries) {
         echo removeslashes($entries);
                $entries2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$entries); }
                $query2 = "SELECT $column ";
                $query2 .= "FROM newbob ";
                $query2 .= "WHERE $column LIKE '%$entries2%'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
                                if (!$result2){
    die ("<br>Database query failed.");
}
                $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

               echo " (" . $rowcount . ")<br>";
 }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm getting back, if that helps make it clearer.

[image]

Comment: can you highlight where is the problem and what is your desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: you mean __herb's__ and __herbs__ should have the same count instead of them being separate?

Comment: What about `Sandys` and `Sandis`?

Comment: Exactly, there isn't necessarily a problem with what the function is doing but, for instance if the script can somehow combine Sandi's and Sandi\'s votes that'd be fantastic.

Even more fantastic would be things like Steve's Steak house and Steve's steakhouse. Sage Brush Grill and Sagebrush Grill ... It's very safe to assume that anything that is a character or so off is the exact same thing.

Comment: Actually, I am getting one "false positive" (if you could call it that) on what there is already. Which shouldn't throw it off a ton over the course of the next month or so.

There's got to be a better way to do this.